# Question regarding math rules for fractions and exponents when isolating variables of interest

Tags: economic-growth

I'm working with growth models in a course, and keep stumbling into this when trying to isolate variables of interest.
I have a formula $y^*=AL^{\alpha-1}$ and I want to isolate $L$ in this expression. When I do this, I get the answer that
$$L=\left(\,\frac{y^*}{A}\right)\,^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$$
According to my lecture slides, the fraction should be flipped and the exponent should now read $1-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha-1$, like so:
$$L=\left(\,\frac{A}{y^*}\right)\,^\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$
I cannot find any hints online as to what I'm doing wrong, hope some of you can explain the reason for this.

Comment: two hints: (i) $1-\alpha = -(\alpha -1)$, (ii) for $x\ne 0,\, x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @VARulle I think you can just post that as the answer.

Comment: @Giskard, O.k., done.

Comment: So, the point is the following: input elasticities of output (namely, $\alpha$ in your model) are generally between 0 and 1 (most of the Cobb-Douglas production functions exhibit decreasing returns to scale). Hence, you generally flip everything, so that you have a clearer representation.

Answer (score 5):

You did nothing wrong. If $A\ne0$, $y^*\ne0$ and $\alpha\ne1$, then
$$\left(\,\frac{y^*}{A}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}=\left(\left(\,\frac{A}{y^*}\right)^{-1}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}=\left(\,\frac{A}{y^*}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}=\left(\,\frac{A}{y^*}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$$